# How can I tell boto3 lambda invoke to use a specified iam role and not the one in my aws config file?

Tags: aws-lambda, azure-functions, boto3

I am trying to invoke an aws lambda from an azure function using boto3.  I have everything working using my two personal accounts.  I created an aws configuration file using my personal account details.  Now I have moved both the azure function and aws lambda to my work dev environments.  My work does not want me to use aws credential ("access_key_id" and "secret_access_key").  Is there a way around this?  A way to tell boto3 don't use the credentials in aws config file, instead use this role??

```
client = boto3.client('lambda')

  response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='arn:aws:lambda:us-##-#:##############:function:azure-to-s3',
    InvocationType='Event',
    Payload=json.dumps({
        'file_name': filename,
        'file_bytes': base64.b85encode(rawfile).decode('utf-8'),
    }),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to your work's AWS account via the console, you can give any account permission to invoke a Lambda.

Via the console:

- Browse to the specified Lambda
- Configuration -> Permissions
- Click 'Add permission' under the 'Resource-based policy'-section

The equivalent boto3-function would be `add_permission()`.

After that, you can invoke the Lambda from the Azure account as you would normally, but using your own credentials.
Credentials can be set in one of three ways:

- setting the credentials in ~/.aws/credentials, if you're on a VM
- setting the credentials as environment variables:

  ```
  export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
  export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
  export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
  ```
- setting the credentials as parameters when using boto3:

  ```
  boto3.client("lambda", region_name="us-west-2", aws_access_key_id="ak", aws_secret_access_key="sk")
  ```

Comment: The add_permission would be added to he aws lambda being called by the azure function correct?  If i'm correct the add_permission basically says "this role/user/group" is allowed to invoke this lambda.  Since the function is in azure not aws it won't have iam roles/users/groups.  So i'm not understanding how giving an aws role access to invoke the lambda would allow the function to invoke it.

Comment: @johnsontroye I've edited my answer to be more specific on how to use your own credentials in Azure